# Get storage path from Google Storage signed url

Tags: url, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

The recommended way to get a public readable reference to a Google Storage file seems to be to use [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls).

I need to retrieve a storage reference based on the URL, so that when my database record is deleted I can delete its files from Storage as well.

The signed URL for a file stored in `path/file.jpeg` seems to follow the pattern:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket.name/path%2Ffile.jpeg?foobar
```

So I am currently using a regex to take the text between `bucket.name` and the `?` character, then replacing `%2F` with `/`. I would like to know:

- Is this reliable?
- Is there any API in official libraries that does this for me? Could not find any.
- Is there any better approach? Like storing the storage path in the database record, along with the signed url (seems overkill to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to get a public readable reference to a Cloud Storage object is just by [allowing public access](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public) to it, by doing this you will get a URL in the form of storage.googleapis.com/[your-bucket]/[path-to-file]/[file].

-Is this reliable?
Signed URLs are meant to be used when requiring access (read, write or delete) just for a limited time, thus using a Signed URL for the current application needs may not be the         best approach since you are using regex to get the appropriate URL path but ignoring all the text after “?” which requires certain computational process to be signed.

-Is there any API in official libraries that does this for me? Could not find any.
Not sure if you are referring to extracting the path from the signed URL, if that is the case then the answer is no.

-Is there a better approach? 
Using the public access permission could be another option. If you are using the signed url to also have delete permissions but not really using the limited time functionality then the best approach is to use object public access, create a service account with enough permissions (delete Cloud Storage objects) and use the [storage client library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-objects#storage-delete-object-java) to delete the object from the bucket when the DB record is deleted.

Comment: Thanks. But the issue is the same, isn't it? If I allow public access I get an URL (like a signed URL but without the ?). I would still have to use a regex to extract the database path (to use it as an input to the storage client library). Right?

Comment: Yes, you will need to extract it but you won't need to replace characters (%2F) and you won't need to go through the full Signed URL creation process since no limit-time is needed. But it is just one more approach that you may want to consider for the solution. In any case the client library does not offer a specific way to extract the path from the signed URL.

Comment: OK! Thanks for answering!